# TIFF image is black in ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, image, 3d-analyst, arcscene

.tiff image is black. I've opened it in QGIS without any problem but in ArcScene the image is black. The weight of image is 121gb(it is country .tiff image)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not mention which version of QGIS you are running but I assume you are running QGIS on a modern 64 bit computer with >4GB of RAM.  ArcScene is a 32 bit application.  It looks like your 121GB file is just too big for ArcScene to render.  You do not mention which version of ArcScene you are running but [this link calls out file size limitations](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002036) in older (still 32 bit) version of their software.

Comment: Thx. QGIS version is 3.16 Hannover

Comment: Have you seen qgis2threejs?   https://medium.com/the-pointscene-diaries/3d-map-qgis-guide-4688975b8fb4.  If you can accept my answer I would appreciate it.

Comment: image CRS(coordinat reference system) wasn't set. After setting crs of image to wgs 84 3857 using Define Projection tool in ArcGIS Pro the problem was solved